# Cascading between 2 datagridview in C# windows application

Tags: c#

I have 2 datagridview in my window form.I want to add functionality that when user click on the cell of 1st datagridview related information should get display in datagridview 2.Just like cascading .
For both datagridview i have made a function
Code of datagridview which will display data :-

```
 public bool CallList()
        {
        bool breturn = false;
        System.Data.DataSet objDataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
        System.Data.DataSet objDataSet1 = new System.Data.DataSet();
        modGlobalMembers.Enum_DBReturnValues_TriState enumIsRecords = modGlobalMembers.Enum_DBReturnValues_TriState.ERROR_RETURN;
        clsColumnInfoGrid objGridColumnInfo = new clsColumnInfoGrid();
        string strListLoadSQL = "";
        ArrayList objalListLoadWhereClause = new ArrayList();
        string strListLoadOrderByClause = "";

        try
        {
            pnlList.Visible = true;
            pnlInputMaster.Visible = false;
            atxtSearch.Focus();
            m_strKeyValueCurrent = modGlobalMembers.g_const_strUPDATENONE_VALUE;

            objDataSet = modCFCMembers.g_objDBTransactionsMod.SelectSQL("SELECT config_id as " + modGlobalMembers.g_const_strSELECTSQL_IDCOLUMN + ",department_id " + ",config_description,user_id,is_active " + " FROM EST_PAYBILL_CONFIG_M", "", null, "CONFIG_DESCRIPTION", "EST_PAYBILL_CONFIG_M", ref enumIsRecords);

            if (enumIsRecords == AccSchool.CommonMembers.modGlobalMembers.Enum_DBReturnValues_TriState.ALL_RETURN)
            {
                //'Data has been retrieved
                acmbSearchColumns.Enabled = true;
                atxtSearch.Enabled = true;

                //'Set GridColumnInfo object
                //objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn(modGlobalMembers.g_const_strSELECTSQL_IDCOLUMN, "CATEGORY_ID", 0, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_String, false);
                ////objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn("HEAD_IS_ALLOWANCE", "Payroll Type", 145, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_String, true);
                ////objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn("HEAD_IS_ALLOWANCE_BIT", "HEAD_IS_ALLOWANCE_BIT", 0, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_String, false);
                //objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn("CATEGORY_NAME", "Designation Name", 225, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_String, true);
                //objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn("CATEGORY_SHORT_NAME", "Short Name", 95, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_String, true);
                //objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn("CATEGORY_GROUP", "Category Group", 95, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_String, true);
                //objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn("ALLOCATED_PERCENTAGE", "Allocated Percentage", 95, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_Integer, true);
                //// objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn("GRADE_ID", "Grade", 95, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_Integer, true);
                ////objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn("CADRE", "Cadre", 95, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_Integer, true);
                ////objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn("EQUIVALANT_POST", "Equi.Post", 95, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_Integer, true);
                ////objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn("PRIORITY_ID", "Priority_id", 95, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_String, true);
                objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn(modGlobalMembers.g_const_strSELECTSQL_IDCOLUMN, "CONFIG_ID", 0, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_String, false);
                objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn("config_description", "Config Description", 900, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_String, true);
                objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn("department_id", "Department id", 95, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_String, false);
                objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn("salary_head_property", "Salary Head Property", 150, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_String, false);
                objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn("user_id", "User Id", 100, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_Integer, false);
                objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn("is_active", "Status", 100, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_Integer, false);

                //objDataSet = modCFCMembers.g_objDBTransactionsMod.SelectSQL("select emp_title||'_'||emp_fname||'_'||emp_sname||'_'||emp_surname a,config_id b from est_employee_m a,est_emp_advances_detail b where a.emp_id=b.emp_id", "", null, "CONFIG_DESCRIPTION", "EST_PAYBILL_CONFIG_M", ref enumIsRecords);

                ////objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn("HEAD_EFFECTIVE_DATE", "Effective Date", 125, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_DateTime, true);
                ////objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn("ACTIVE_FLAG", "IsActive", 55, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_Integer, true);
                ////objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn("HEAD_INACTIVE_DATE", "Inactive Date",150, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_DateTime, true);

                m_strSearchFilter = "";

                breturn = modGlobalMembers.g_objGlobalMethods.FillDataGridViewWithDesign(dgvList, m_objBindingSource, "ID_COLUMN", objGridColumnInfo, 525, objDataSet, "EST_PAYBILL_CONFIG_M", null, false);


                //'dgvList.Columns("SAL_PAY_VALUE").CellTemplate.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight



                SetGridValues();

            }
            else
            {
                acmbSearchColumns.Enabled = false;
                atxtSearch.Enabled = false;

                while (dgvList.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    dgvList.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
                }

                ////for (int iCountRows = 0; iCountRows <= dgvList.Rows.Count - 1; iCountRows++)
                ////{
                ////    dgvList.Rows.RemoveAt(iCountRows);
                ////}

                modGlobalMembers.g_objPopup = new AccSchool.Popup();
                modGlobalMembers.g_objPopup.ShowPopup("There are no records for Paybill Config  to display!", "", true, modGlobalMembers.Enum_DBModes.DELETE_MODE);
                breturn = false;
            }

            acmbSearchColumns.Items.Clear();
            for (int iCountColumns = 0; iCountColumns <= objGridColumnInfo.Length - 1; iCountColumns++)
            {
                if (objGridColumnInfo.IsVisible(iCountColumns))
                {

                    if (objGridColumnInfo.ColumnName(iCountColumns) != "HEAD_IS_ALLOWANCE" && objGridColumnInfo.ColumnName(iCountColumns) != "HEAD_IS_ALLOWANCE_BIT")
                    {

                        acmbSearchColumns.Items.Add(new clsValueDataPairGrid(objGridColumnInfo.ColumnName(iCountColumns), objGridColumnInfo.HeaderText(iCountColumns), objGridColumnInfo.ColumnType(iCountColumns)));

                    }
                }
            }

            CallClear();

            return breturn;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }


    }
```

Code of datagridview 2 where it should display related data of datagridview1

```
private void dgvList_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
        DataGridViewRow dr = dgvList.SelectedRows[0];
        atxtconfigdiscrip.Text = dr.Cells["config_description"].Value.ToString();
        acmbdep.SelectedValue = dr.Cells["department_id"].Value.ToString();
        acmbuserid.SelectedValue = dr.Cells["user_id"].Value.ToString();

        //bool breturn = false;
        System.Data.DataSet objDataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
        modGlobalMembers.Enum_DBReturnValues_TriState enumIsRecords = modGlobalMembers.Enum_DBReturnValues_TriState.ERROR_RETURN;
        clsColumnInfoGrid objGridColumnInfo = new clsColumnInfoGrid();
        string strListLoadSQL = "";
        ArrayList objalListLoadWhereClause = new ArrayList();
        string strListLoadOrderByClause = "";
        //object objValue = null;
        //string[] strArr = null;

        try
        {
            // pnlList.Visible = true;
            // pnlInputMaster.Visible = false;
            while (dgvList.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dgvList.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            atxtSearch.Focus();
            //m_strKeyValueCurrent = modGlobalMembers.g_const_strUPDATENONE_VALUE;
            strListLoadSQL = "select emp_title||'_'||emp_fname||'_'||emp_sname||'_'||emp_surname EmployeeName,config_id b from est_employee_m EmployeeName,est_emp_advances_detail b";
            //strListLoadSQL = strListLoadSQL  + "from est_employee_m EmployeeName,est_emp_advances_detail b";
            objalListLoadWhereClause.Add("EmployeeName.emp_id=b.emp_id");
            objDataSet = modCFCMembers.g_objDBTransactionsMod.SelectSQL(strListLoadSQL, "", objalListLoadWhereClause, strListLoadOrderByClause, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strLISTSQL_TABLENAME, ref enumIsRecords);

            if (enumIsRecords == AccSchool.CommonMembers.modGlobalMembers.Enum_DBReturnValues_TriState.ALL_RETURN)
            {
                //'Data has been retrieved
                // acmbSearchColumns.Enabled = true;
                //atxtSearch.Enabled = true;

                //'Set GridColumnInfo object
                //objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn(modGlobalMembers.g_const_strSELECTSQL_IDCOLUMN, "SAL_GROUP_ID", 0, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_String, false);
                objGridColumnInfo.AddColumn("emp_title||'_'||emp_fname||'_'||emp_sname||'_'||emp_surname", "Employee Name", 270, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strDT_String, true);

                dgv3.DataSource = objDataSet;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            {
                //return false;
            }



            //    // modGlobalMembers.Enum_DBReturnValues_TriState enumReturn = modGlobalMembers.Enum_DBReturnValues_TriState.ERROR_RETURN;
            //    //string strListLoadSQL = "";
            //    //ArrayList objalListLoadWhereClause = new ArrayList();
            //    //string strListLoadOrderByClause = "";
            //    //System.Data.DataSet objDataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
            //    //bool bReturn = false;

            //    //object objValue = null;
            //    ////object objValue2 = null;

            //    //try
            //    //{
            //    //    //strListLoadSQL = "SELECT " + atxtdeptname.AccSqlSPArgumentName.Substring(1, atxtdeptname.AccSqlSPArgumentName.Length - 1) + " AS " + atxtdeptname.Name + "," + atxtsname.AccSqlSPArgumentName.Substring(1, atxtsname.AccSqlSPArgumentName.Length - 1) + " AS " + atxtsname.Name +  "," + "IS_ACTIVE AS IS_ACTIVE";
            //    //    strListLoadSQL = "SELECT " + " e.department_id AS " + acmbdep.Name +
            //    //       ",e.config_description AS " + atxtconfigdiscrip.Name + ",s.emp_id as " + acmbddopaybill.Name + ",e.user_id AS " + acmbuserid.Name + ",e.is_active AS " + acbisactive.Name;

            //    //    strListLoadSQL = strListLoadSQL + " FROM EST_PAYBILL_CONFIG_M e left join EST_PAYBILL_CONFIG_D s on(e.config_id=s.config_id)";

            //    //    objalListLoadWhereClause.Add("CONFIG_ID= \'" + m_strKeyValueCurrent + "\'");


            //    //    objDataSet = modCFCMembers.g_objDBTransactionsMod.SelectSQL(strListLoadSQL, "", objalListLoadWhereClause, strListLoadOrderByClause, modGlobalMembers.g_const_strLISTSQL_TABLENAME, ref enumReturn);


            //    //    if (enumReturn == AccSchool.CommonMembers.modGlobalMembers.Enum_DBReturnValues_TriState.ALL_RETURN)
            //    //    {
            //    //        objValue = objDataSet.Tables[modGlobalMembers.g_const_strLISTSQL_TABLENAME].Rows[0]["is_active"];

            //    //        acbisactive.Checked = true;

            //    //        if (objValue != null && objValue != System.DBNull.Value)
            //    //        {
            //    //            if (objValue.ToString().ToUpper() == bool.TrueString.ToUpper())
            //    //            {
            //    //                acbisactive.Checked = true;
            //    //            }
            //    //            else
            //    //            {
            //    //                acbisactive.Checked = false;
            //    //            }
            //    //        }
            //    //    }
            //    //}
            //    //catch (Exception)
            //    //{
            //    //    //return false;
            //    //}
            //    //acbisactive.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dr.Cells["is_active"].ToString());
            //    //calldgvdocument();

            //    //is_active
            //    //for (int x = 0; x < dgvList.Rows.Count; x++)
            //    //{
            //    //    if (dgvList.Rows[x].Cells["is_active"].Value.ToString().Equals("true"))
            //    //    {
            //    //        acbisactive.Checked = true;
            //    //    }
            //    //else if (dgvList.Rows[x].Cells["is_active"].ToString().Equals("false"))
            //    //{
            //    //    acbisactive.Checked =false;
            //    //}

            //}

        }
    }
```

I hvae write code of datagridview2 in mouse_click() event of datagridview1 as shown below

Comment: Why is it tagged with `php` and `java` ?

Comment: Very hard to sort through that wall of code, and I'm not seeing where you are struggling. This looks to be straight master detail, ie your top grid could be a listbox for instance.

Comment: take example from your own explain me through coding